# How to get a modern experience list on a page without losing the modern experience

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have made a list with the modern experience look. But when i put the modern experience list as a webpart on a page i get the classic view. How can i get the modern experience view?

Gr. P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the experience of your page?

Please add the modern list in modern page.

Comment: I want to add the modern experience list on a wikipage without losing the modern view

Comment: You can't. Use a modern page to get the modern list view in a webpart.

Comment: So if understand it correctly. If i have a list with classic view i can put it on a wiki page. But a list with modern experience view i have to put it on a modern page. Right?

Comment: The Wiki page is a classic page, and any web part in this page will display the classic view.

Comment: Yes, you are right. please remember to mark the reply as answer if it helps you.

Comment: Yes thank you for the information. Gr. p